# Is it possible to install Windows 2000 onto a bootable USB-Drive?

Tags: usb, portable, windows-2000

I have got a gigantic collection of old games **for Windows 2000** from a friend. I really wanted to try those so I instantly tried to install the ones I'm interested in. I tried to install them to my new Gaming-PC with Windows 10 and they seemed to install just fine but after I ran these they just crashed. That was a little disappointed but I didn't give up. So I tried the "broken" game in compatibility mode. It still didn't work. Then I started looking for old Windows 7 and Vista laptops from my basement and installing the game on them. Windows Vista absolutely didn't do anything but complain about drivers missing for the game and Windows 7 had the same problem as 10. Well, that was all several months ago. Today I happened to come across the games again and immediately felt like playing them again. I think maybe I can install Windows 2000 on a USB stick, which would be quite practical since I can then take it with me everywhere and even without game CDs I can feel a kind of nostalgia when I plug it into a computer. I did a lot of research on the Internet as to whether it could work, but I couldn't find any instructions on how to install Windows 2K on a stick or whether it was possible at all. Now I want to ask this question here. **Is it possible to install Windows 2000 onto a USB stick? Or at least XP?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if you can manage a PC that is capable of running old windows version such as windows 2000, then it is possible. There is an amazing guide at https://techuserfriendly.com/how-to-install-setup-windows-xp-2000-2003-vista-7-from-usb-drive-key-stick/

Comment: You are correct. I even have a copy of 2000 lying around but I would like to use an USB-Stick. But thanks anyway.

Comment: It takes a lot of hacking to get W2K or XP to boot and run off of a usb drive, and does not always work after many hours of hacking the installation files.>>>>>https://web.archive.org/web/20060602041705/http://www.ngine.de/index.jsp?pageid=4176